# ¿Como mostrar ventana con mensaje de datos enviados de un formulario html?

Tags: javascript, html

tengo un nuevo problema.

De mi formulario ya conseguí que al momento de dar clic en el botón enviar, se marquen en rojo los campos que no han sido contestados, en otras palabras, ya se validan los `placeholder` y los `radiobutton/checkbox`.

Ahora tengo que hacer que después de haber llenado todos los campos y dar clic en el botón de "Enviar", tras validar todo, se envíen los datos pero que se muestre una ventana la cual tenga de mensaje "Envío de datos correcto" ¿Desea responder otro formulario? Y dos botones uno de "Cancelar" que cierre todo el formulario/pagina y otro de "Aceptar" que me permita volver a contestar el formulario desde 0, o sea, que no se queden datos guardados del anterior.

De momento nada se envía a la base de datos porque no existe, es solo para fines de funcionalidad, que se vea que funciona el formulario.

¿Como hago esto de la venta con `JavaScript`?

Por su amable atención gracias.

Aquí mi código **`JavaScript`**:

```js
function salta()
{
    var number = document.getElementById("selectFormularios").value;  /* esta variable representa el obtener la referencia de la lista desplegable del option */
    var e = document.getElementsByClassName("formulario");    /* esta variable permite seleccionar un elemento del documento por medio del valor del atributo id que se le ha asignado */

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(e, function(el) { el.style.display = "none"; }); /* Esta parte oculta todo lo que hay en el Call, uno por uno y les pone display none */
        
    switch (number)
    {
        case '2':
            document.getElementById("Tabla3").style.display = "block";
            break;
        case '3':
            document.getElementById("Tabla4").style.display = "block";
            break;
        case '4':
            document.getElementById("Tabla5").style.display = "block";
            break;
        case '5':
            document.getElementById("Tabla6").style.display = "block";
            break;
        case '6':
            document.getElementById("Tabla7").style.display = "block";
            break;
        case '7':
            document.getElementById("Tabla8").style.display = "block";
            break;
        case '8':
            document.getElementById("Tabla9").style.display = "block";
            break;
        case '9':
            document.getElementById("Tabla10").style.display = "block";
            break;
        case '10':
            document.getElementById("Tabla11").style.display = "block";
            break;
        case '11':
            document.getElementById("Tabla12").style.display = "block";
            default:
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(e, function(el) {
                el.style.display = "none";
            });
        break;
    }
}

function formulario()
{
    var formulario = document.getElementsByName('formulario')[1],
    elementos = formulario.elements,
    boton = document.getElementById('btn');
    
    var validarNombre = function(e){
        if (formulario.nombre.value == 0){
        alert("completa el campo");
        e.preventDefault();
        }
    };
    
    var validarRadio = function()
    {
        if (formulario.option[0].checked == true || formulario.option[1].checked == true || formulario.option[2].checked == true{
        } else {
        alert("Selecciona una opcion");
        e.preventDefault();
        }
    
    var validar = function(e){
        validarNombre(e)
        validarRadio(e)
    };
    
    formulario.addEventListener("submit", validar);
    }
}
```

Y aquí mi código **`HTML`**:

```html
<html lang="en-us">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title> Formato para equipos moviles</title>
    <!-- Meta tags -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <!-- Meta tags -->
    <!--stylesheets-->
    <link href="style.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media="all">
    <!--//style sheet end here-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,700italic,300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

    <!-- Este es el titulo del formulario --->
    <h1 class="header-w3ls">
        Formato de Inspección Pre-operativa<br>
        para Equipos Móviles
      </h1>
    <!-- Fin del titulo del formulario --->
    <!-- Seccion de la primer parte del formulario donde se llenan los campos solicitados -->
    <div class="online-w3l-form">
        <div class="main-headder">
        </div>
        <div class="appointment-w3">
            <form name="formulario" action="" method="get">
                <div class="main">
                    <div class="form-left-w3l">
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <p>Nombre de la instalación</p>
                        <input type="text" class="top-up" id="Nombre-Instalacion" name="Nombre" placeholder="" required />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-right-w3ls">
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <p>Área</p>
                        <input type="text" class="top-up" id="Area" required name="Nombre" placeholder="">
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-right-w3ls">
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <p>Fecha:
                            <input type="date" required name="Nombre">
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="main">
                    <div class="form-left-w3l">
                        <p>Nombre del Operador</p>
                        <input type="text" required name="Nombre" id="Nombre-Operador" placeholder="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-right-w3ls">
                        <p>Nombre del Supervisor o Responsable de Área</p>
                        <input type="text" required name="Nombre" id="Nombre-Supervisor" placeholder="">
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="main">
                    <div class="form-right-w32">
                        <p>Marca y tipo del equipo</p>
                        <input type="text" class="top-up" id="Marca-Equipo" required name="Nombre" placeholder="">
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-right-w33s">
                        <p>Lectura del contador-Horometro (si aplica)</p>
                        <input type="text" required name="Nombre" id="Lec1" placeholder="Inicio">
                        <input type="text" required name="Nombre" id="Lec2" placeholder="Fin">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="main">
                    <div class="form-left-w3l">
                        <p>Número/código del equipo</p>
                        <input type="text" required name="Nombre" id="Codigo-Equipo" placeholder="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-right-w33s">
                        <p>Lectura de combustible (si aplica)</p>
                        <input type="text" required name="Nombre" id="Lec3" placeholder="Inicio">
                        <input type="text" required name="Nombre" id="Lec4" placeholder="Fin">
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <br>

                <!-- Fin de la primer parte del formulario -->

                <!-- Cinta verde de titulo del segundo formulario -->
                <div class="caja3">
                    <p>II. VEHICULOS UTILITARIOS y DE TRANSPORTE DE PERSONAL</p>
                </div>
                <!-- Fin de cinta verde de titulo del segundo formulario -->

                <!-- Segundo formulario--->

                <table class="Datos2">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                <h2 id="encabezado"><p>Inspeccion del equipo</p></h2>
                            </th>
                            <th width="40">
                                <h3 id="unico">CR</h3>
                            </th>
                            <th width="40">
                                <h2 id="encabezado">C</h2>
                            </th>
                            <th width="40">
                                <h2 id="encabezado">C/N</h2>
                            </th>
                            <th width="40">
                                <h2 id="encabezado">N/A</h2>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Llanta de refacción (inflado / desgaste / deformaciones)</td>
                            <td width="80" align="center" width="25">3</td>
                            <td align="center">
                                <input type="radio" required name="check25" value="C">
                                <td align="center">
                                    <input type="radio" required name="check25" value="C/N">
                                    <td align="center">
                                        <input type="radio" required name="check25" value="N/A">
                                    </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Herramientas - kit de emergencia (sin daños / completas)</td>
                            <td align="center" width="25">3</td>
                            <td align="center">
                                <input type="radio" required name="check26" value="C">
                                <td align="center">
                                    <input type="radio" required name="check26" value="C/N">
                                    <td align="center">
                                        <input type="radio" required name="check26" value="N/A">
                                    </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Roll bar - pick up (colocada y sin deformación en su estructura)</td>
                            <td align="center" width="25">3</td>
                            <td align="center">
                                <input type="radio" required name="check27" value="C">
                                <td align="center">
                                    <input type="radio" required name="check27" value="C/N">
                                    <td align="center">
                                        <input type="radio" required name="check27" value="N/A">
                                    </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Pértiga con banderín - pick up uso en cantera (colocada y sin deformaciones)</td>
                            <td align="center" width="25">3</td>
                            <td align="center">
                                <input type="radio" required name="check28" value="C">
                                <td align="center">
                                    <input type="radio" required name="check28" value="C/N">
                                    <td align="center">
                                        <input type="radio" required name="check28" value="N/A">
                                    </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Otro: Especificar</td>
                            <td align="center" width="25">3</td>
                            <td align="center">
                                <input type="radio" required name="check29" value="C">
                                <td align="center">
                                    <input type="radio" required name="check29" value="C/N">
                                    <td align="center">
                                        <input type="radio" required name="check29" value="N/A">
                                    </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <!-- Botón envio de formulario y validación de datos -->
                <button id="submit" type="submit">Enviar</button>
                <!-- Botón envio de formulario y validación de datos -->
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <!-- Pie de pagina -->

    <!-- Fin del pie de pagina -->
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Agrega el código que tienes para tratar de replicarlo. Pásate por [esta sección](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Para que conozcas como elaborar preguntas que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad.

Comment: Te sugiero leas [ask] para que sepas cómo realizar una buena pregunta y también [mcve], para que tus preguntas sean mejor recibidas por la comunidad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En la función llamada salta, haces un **switch** que dependiendo del valor de una variable muestra u oculta ciertas tablas, y si el **switch** pasa por la sentencia **default**, ocultas de una todas las tablas, aparte fíjate bien por favor que en el código cada *string/número* que evalúas no coincide con el número de la tabla que estás mostrando u ocultando:

```
switch (number)
    {
        case '2'://numero evaluado no coincide con el número de la tabla.
            document.getElementById("Tabla3").style.display = "block";
            break;
   }
```

No sé si fue hecho esto aposta de esta manera y tú estructura la manejas así, pero si fue hecho aposta así y tú estructura funciona de esta manera, perfecto no hay problema, por otro lado.

¿Porqué hacer un switch si puedes ahorrarte un montón de líneas de código haciendo lo siguiente?:

- En vez de poner un ID a cada una de las tablas para ser accedidas por medio de `document.getElementById`, ponle una misma clase a cada una de tus tablas en el HTML.
- Crea una variable global llamada por ejemplo tablas, y según el nombre de la clase que le hayas dado a las tablas guardas las referencias a esas tablas de esta manera:

  `let misTablas = document.getElementsByClassName("tablas-contenido");`
- Como último paso, en vez de usar ese switch largo, dependiendo del número que tiene la variable numero.

vas a hacer algo como lo siguiente:

```
if(numero < misTablas.length && numero >= 0){    
     misTablas[parseInt(numero)].style.display = "block";    
  }else{    
     for(let i = 0; i < misTablas.length; i++){    
        misTablas[i].style.display = "none";    
    }    
}
```

Por otro lado, para hacer lo que requieres (mostrar un mensaje de validación y ejecutar una cosa o la otra dependiendo de lo que el usuario le haya dado clic), normalmente no recomendaría usar este tipo de cosas, ya que pausan la ejecución del programa, pero igual no se acerca de una mejor opción por lo que te comparto la que sé:

Usa la función `confirm`, además deberías crear una función que se encargue específicamente de mostrarte este tipo de alerta (confirm):

```
function mostrarConfirmar(mensaje){

    const confirmar = confirm(mensaje);
    return confirmar.value;

}
```

Y entonces supongamos que el usuario ya ingresó todos los datos y que los datos están correctos, entonces en la parte donde requieras mostrar este mensaje, usas esta función de la siguiente manera:

```
let confirmado = mostrarConfirmar("¡Hola señor usuario!, sus datos han sido correctamente enviados, toque aceptar para volver a enviar otro formulario, toque cancelar para salir.");

 if(confirmado){

    let numero = document.getElementById("selectFormularios");

    //Asignamos una tabla inexistente para luego
    //Usar la función saltar y así "limpiar" de pantalla
    //Todas las tablas.
    numero.value = "-1";
    saltar();

    //Preguntamos el formulario que desea visitar
    let formularioEscogido = parseInt(prompt("¿Qué formulario deseas llenar?, (Pon un número)"));
    //Saltamos al formulario.
    saltar();

 }else{

    let numero = document.getElementById("selectFormularios");

    numeros.value = "-1";
    saltar();

 }
```

Otra optimización que se le puede hacer al código es que en la función `validarRadio`, tienes un `if` vacío, debes evitar este tipo de cosas, podrías solucionarlo de esta forma:

```
if(!(formulario.option[0].checked || formulario.option[1].checked || formulario.option[2].checked)){

     alert("Selecciona una opción");
     e.preventDefault();

}
```

Y el `else` se quitaría del código, creo que eso sería todo el código, el código lo he hecho en el celular por lo que puede que no esté correctamente formateado, espero sea de ayuda!